# Managing Data in Multiple Databases

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, uniqueidentifier, multiple-databases

I work on a project that has two parts.  The first part is data entered by the customers called Event data.  This data gets posted to the internet so that customers can edit their information.  The second part is Results data.  The event data is copied from the public database to our lab and the analysts run complex calculations to generate the results.  The results portion of an individual database can run into the terabyte range.  To add to the complexity we have close to 10 study areas each with their own database because of the size.

We are in the process of doing a major update and I have the opportunity to make some changes to improve performance.  Right now we have a database for each study area that includes both the events and results.

One of the options being proposed is to separate the events and results for each study area into separate databases. I know if I use a unique identifier I can tie the results for each event across the two databases.  Once the results are generated I will need to generate reports that pull data from both the events and results databases for a study area.

Another option that was proposed was to combine all of the events into one database.  This would make posting the events to the public site a lot easier as we would only have one database to transfer back and forth.  However, the results databases need to remain separate because they are so large.  I like this idea but am not sure how difficult it will be to implement.  I was wondering if anyone had every done anything similar and had any advice.

I did read the post at [Managing multiple databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448177/managing-multiple-databases)

I am working with classified data in a closed enclave so while I have considerable processing power, storage and some reasonably hefty network switches I do not have unlimited resources.  I am running SQL Server 2008 but I am hoping to upgrade to either SQL Server 2014 or 2016 in the near future.

Let me know if any of this does not make sense and I will try to clarify.

Comment: "because they are so large" How large?  Why do you think you can't use a single database, if that makes things easier?

Comment: You may want to consider using an analytical database rather than a transactional one for your analytics. As far as OLAP databases go, I am most familiar with Redshift, for which the cost per terabyte can be as low as 1k per year (that is with a reserved 3 year instance paid up front, so expect to pay more).

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - The events portions of the databases are not particularly large.  When we add the results they wind up between 2 - 10 TB for each study area.  The reports we have to generate are complex and can take an hour to a day or more to run.  I end up with multiple nested queries and complex joins to get the reports the customers require.   The larger the database the longer the reports take to run.  My manager wants me to reduce those run times, hence the need for the separate results databases.  I am wondering if there is an advantage to separate events databases versus one.

Comment: "I am wondering if there is an advantage to separate events databases versus one" Probably not.  And once you are on SQL 2016 or SQL 2017 you'll have good options for reducing the query runtimes.